# Swift launch view only when data received

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm getting info from an API using the following function where I pass in a string of a word. Sometimes the word doesn't available in the API if it doesn't available I generate a new word and try that one.
The problem is because this is an asynchronous function when I launch the page where the value from the API appears it is sometimes empty because the function is still running in the background trying to generate a word that exists in the API. 
How can I make sure the page launches only when the data been received from the api ?

```
static func wordDefin (word : String, completion: @escaping (_ def: String )->(String)) {
        let wordEncoded = word.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        let uri = URL(string:"https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=he&morph=false&text=" + wordEncoded! )
        if let unwrappedURL = uri {
            var request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL);request.addValue("Basic bmV0YXlhbWluOk5ldGF5YW1pbjg5Kg==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                do {
                if let data = data {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let empty = try decoder.decode(Empty.self, from: data)
                    if (empty.results?.isEmpty)!{
                        print("oops looks like the word :" + word)
                        game.wordsList.removeAll(where: { ($0) == game.word })
                        game.floffWords.removeAll(where: { ($0) == game.word })
                        helper.newGame()
                    } else {
                        let definition =  empty.results?[0].senses?[0].definition
                        _ = completion(definition ?? "test")
                        return
                    }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("connection")
                    print(error)
                }
        }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: whatever part of your code that is launching that page...just do that from the completionHandler of the your `wordDefin` func

Comment: I assume by page you mean a `UIViewController`?

Comment: @bsod that's right. I should have been more clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop a view controller from "launching" itself (except not to push/present/show it at all). Once you push/present/show it, its lifecycle cannot—and should not—be stopped. Therefore, it's your responsibility to load the appropriate UI for the "loading state", which may be a blank view controller with a loading spinner. You can do this however you want, including loading the full UI with `.isHidden = true` set for all view objects. The idea is to do as much pre-loading of the UI as possible while the database is working in the background so that when the data is ready, you can display the full UI with as little work as possible.

What I'd suggest is after you've loaded the UI in its "loading" configuration, download the data as the final step in your flow and use a completion handler to finish the task:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData { (result) in
        // load full UI
    }

}
```

Your data method may look something like this:

```
private func loadData(completion: @escaping (_ result: Result) -> Void) {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Consider creating a data manager that operates along the following lines. Because the data manager is a class (a reference type), when you pass it forward to other view controllers, they all point to the same instance of the manager. Therefore, changes that any of the view controllers make to it are seen by the other view controllers. That means when you push a new view controller and it's time to update a label, access it from the `data` property. And if it's not ready, wait for the data manager to notify the view controller when it is ready.

```
class GameDataManager {

    // stores game properties
    // updates game properties
    // does all thing game data

    var score = 0
    var word: String?

}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    let data = GameDataManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // when you push to another view controller, point it to the data manager
        let someVC = SomeOtherViewController()
        someVC.data = data

    }

}

class SomeOtherViewController: UIViewController {

    var data: GameDataManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let word = data?.word {
            print(word)
        }

    }

}

class AnyViewController: UIViewController {

    var data: GameDataManager?

}
```

Comment: If I do that then it will only try to get data once the view is being pushed the idea is that when the app is launched it will start getting the data already but as mentioned sometimes because the word isn't available in the API it takes longer and then once the game view is pushed i get empty text

Comment: Then don't incorporate the data object into the view controller, keep them separate. When the data object is ready, have it notify the view controller to load the UI. If the view controller is not yet ready, then this call will do nothing. Therefore, when the view controller is ready, have it call the data object for data so that it can load its UI. But if the data object is not yet ready, then this call will also do nothing. But both cannot fail, one must succeed. Either the data object is ready before the VC or the VC is ready before the data object, so just have them call each other.

Comment: indeed, but as I'm new to swift I'm not sure how to do it. Is there a way I can have a bool and observer to that bool and once the bool changes to true the loading screen will end and load the UI ?

Comment: You can do it however it works and that is one way but there is usually a good way and a not so good way. The better way, IMO, would be to create an object that handles your data and link it with your view controller and simply call a function in the view controller when the data is ready. This way, the view controller can also request data from that object if it's ready when it's pushed.

Comment: I still cannot seem to update the text after the View has already been pushed. It will only update it if I exit and go inside otherwise it will show empty

Comment: Post your code in a gist on Git Hub and I can take a look.

Comment: thank you very much.
https://gist.github.com/netayamin/187ed6930d4b5bbfe973783ec129d8ec

 quickMatchGame.swift is where I want to change the text label once the function of newGame completed

Comment: Instead of creating a game struct, create one data class. Remember, structs are value types, which means when you pass them around, you're passing around brand new copies every time. Therefore, changes to one struct will not be reflected in the other structs. If you make your data object a class (a reference type), then whenever you pass it around, it will always point to the same copy.

Comment: thank you very much! I will check it out and see if I can make it work